# nextInt(int, int) symbol cannot be found when it's called from a java.util.Random object

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA and trying to generate some pseudo random integers.

I tried the following code snippet which complained

> no suitable method found for nextInt(int,int)

```
        java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
        for(int i =0; i<10; i++) {
            int b = rnd.nextInt(5, 10);
            System.out.println(b);
        }
```

I am aware of the alternative way to call nextInt by only providing one argument as the range. But what I don't understand is why nextInt(int, int) cannot be resolved in the case above given that the class java.util.Random implements java.util.random.RandomGenerator which has a default implementation of nextInt(int, int) ?

Comment: `RandomGenerator` was introduced in Java 17 (and in Java 17 your code works for me). What Java version are you using?

Comment: `javac -version` will show you that you're using < 17

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Indeed, the older version was configured in pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=> java.util.random package and the RandomGenerator interface were introduced in Java 17, so you need to be using Java 17 or a later version to utilize this feature. If you are using version of Java which is lower than 17, you won't have access to the nextInt(int, int) method through the Random class.

=> Using Java - 17 you can try below code snippet :

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.random.RandomGenerator;
import java.util.random.RandomGeneratorFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomGenerator generator = RandomGeneratorFactory.getDefault().create();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int b = generator.nextInt(5, 10);
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code fine using JDK 17 and reproduced your error using an early JDK (JDK 12, I think).

java.util.Random appears to exist in JDK 12 (maybe earlier but I didn't check). But the nextInt(int, int) method did not appear until JDK 17 (as the other poster has mentioned). Whereas the earlier JDK does have nextInt(int).

I therefore suggest checking your JRE / JDK settings.